# How to create a file from intent uri in android 11

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to pick a file like docs or pdf from my app and send the file to my server using okhttp. I am getting a uri from using an intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, FILE_PICKER_REQUEST_CODE);
```

I am unable to get the full path of the file for creating a file.
I need paths like this

```
/storage/emulated/0/document/admin.pdf
```

All I need is a file that I can send to the server by any means.Help please.

Comment: what do you get in `onActivityResult` a uri?

Comment: You do not need to convert a nice uri to a full file system path as you can use that uri directly to upload with okhttp.

Comment: @blackapps you don't need inpustream? https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/07/05/multipart-upload-okttp-uri.html

Comment: If you need an input stream then you can directly get an input stream for that uri. And use InputSteamRequestBody. Indeed.. that is the link OP needs.

Comment: @blackapps undestood but can we use uri directly. can you point me to something. i have used inpustream always

Comment: I do not understand your problem as you come up with the right link where the inputstream for an uri is used in InputStreamRequestBody for okhttp. All is there.

Comment: @blackapps anyway thanks i got my answer.

Comment: can anyone provide the code for how to use that uri to send it to server via okhttp